# How do I upload the last 3 files in a directory with WinSCP?

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

Trying to upload the last 3 files in a directory. I figured I can set the last 3 files and make them as an alias but I'm not sure how to do that..

Originally WinSCP was the transferring three specific file names, but it will change daily.

```
"put apple" `
"put pear" `
"put orange" `
```

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul `
  /command `
    "open ftp...." `
    "lcd C:\directorywithfiles" `
    "cd /" `
    # edit this to put the last 3 files
    $dir = "C:\directorywithfiles"
    $lastest = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*" -Exclude "*.php" -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 3
    $latest.name

    #this section is what i'm trying to upload
    "put <$file1>" `
    "put <$file2>" `
    "put <$file3>" `

    "exit"

$winscpResult = $LastExitCode
if ($winscpResult -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Success"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Error"
}

exit $winscpResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to collect the names before your WinSCP commandline, not to break it. And then use syntax like `$($lastest[0])` to refer to the found names:

```
$dir = "C:\directorywithfiles"
$lastest = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*" -Exclude "*.php" -File |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 3

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul `
  /command `
    "open ftp...." `
    "lcd $dir" `
    "cd /" `
    "put $($lastest[0])" `
    "put $($lastest[1])" `
    "put $($lastest[2])" `
    "exit"
```

- Note that I'm reusing the `$dir` variable.
- I'm not sure that the `Select-Object -First 3` does anything useful. It can most likely be removed.

Comment: Very helpful! I had the last 3 files move to a directory, and upload that entire directly and then clear it. But this solutions works much better. Appreciate the input!